# Laravel Basic Auth- get user details

Tags: php, laravel, basic-authentication

In an API, I'm using laravel basic auth. To get details of the user, I need to pass the ID of the user into the request. Is it possible to get details of the user using, authenticated with laravel basic auth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get user id whenever User is logged in by :

```
auth()->id();
```

or

```
Auth::user()->id();
```

FYI: you don't have to send User info in any request you can retrieve his/her basic info from the helper method [`auth()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-auth)

Comment: `Auth()` should be `auth()`, case sensitive systems  would trip up otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current user in your controller by injecting the Illuminate\Http\Request object in to the method.

e.g.

```
public function profile(Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    // do something
```